# How to fix Classes annotated with @Database should extend androidx.room.RoomDatabase

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on room database and currently update my android studio and studio updated with androidx and then after i found this compile error, So please let me know what is that error ?

```
import androidx.room.Database;

@Database (entities = User.class,version = 1)
public abstract class MyDatabase {

    public abstract MyDao myDao();
}
```

Comment: But, the answer in the error. See: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kotlin

Answer (score 8):

```
@Database (entities = User.class,version = 1)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract MyDao myDao();
}
```

As your error message suggested you should extend `RoomDatabase`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a kotlin version if anybody needs it:

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myDao(): MyDao?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend RoomDatabase

```
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase{

}
```